# Can AWS Amplify preview apply on Bitbucket pull request pipeline with similar UI as Github?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, aws-amplify

In my company, we use Amplify to run pipeline and Bitbucket as our git provider.

What I want to do is to have build and test pipeline running whenever a pull request is created.

Additionally, I want to have the build succeed/failed UI display in the pull request.

Referenced to this link: [improve-your-app-testing-with-amplify-consoles-pull-requests-previews-and-cypress-testing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/improve-your-app-testing-with-amplify-consoles-pull-requests-previews-and-cypress-testing/), I found that it is possible in Github with the UI below:

[image]

So, Github can show that AWS Amplify is running test case on it. Is it possible have this feature on Bitbucket? Just like the link below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer.
This is for Github Repositories only.
You can check it here [PR Reviews](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/pr-previews.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has changed in AWS since the other answer was posted but previews *are* successfully being triggered by Bitbucket pull requests in my team's AWS Amplify app.